# How to fit overlapping elements of fixed width within a certain space?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

How can I evenly fit UI elements of a certain fixed width inside a fixed space on the screen? I want to calculate the position to the place the elements inside the space, without scaling or rotating the elements.

For eg: I want to fit the 4 cards which are 500 units in width inside the white space in the bottom which is 1000 units wide.
[image]

expected result: the four cards are placed such that they occupy 1000 units.
[image]

The expected result if there are eight cards.
[image]

Comment: @Kromster I've put the unity3D label back in place since the OP might also refer to how to do it using the Unity3D UI elements (which you don't address in your answer btw)

Comment: @derHugo okay, it won't do any harm. But the OPs problem and requested solution (and accepted solution) clearly indicate that it is engine-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
card_offset = (total_width - card_width) / (number_of_cards - 1) * card_index;
```

Example:

```
1st card offset = (1000 - 500) / (4 - 1) * 0 = 0
2st card offset = (1000 - 500) / (4 - 1) * 1 = 167
3st card offset = (1000 - 500) / (4 - 1) * 2 = 334
4st card offset = (1000 - 500) / (4 - 1) * 3 = 500
```